# Send mail using mailtrap in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer, mailer

I am sending mail using mailtrap. mailtrap received mail in inbox, it says:

```
From:   Example <hello@example.com>
To: <maymail@gmail.com>
```

but the problem is I don't get any mail on `maymail@gmail.com`, not in inbox, not in spam. so what is the problem?

Comment: There isn't a problem. That's the point of Mailtrap - it **traps** emails so they don't get accidentally sent to real people while you're building the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mailtrap` does not send any mail to any mail address, it using for fake mail, so you can see your send mail on your `mailtrap` inbox after login to `mailtrap` service

Answer (score 0):

Remove the mailtrap as default mailing driver and setup your smtp configurations and give a try.